# What are the methods to protect against session-hijacking without httpOnly support?

Tags: android, security, httponly

I'm going to be building my first mobile web app, and I found out that Android 2.3's browser doesn't implement httponly.

What are some techniques to mitigate this problem?  Is this a lost cause?

Comment: There are plenty of attack vectors you need to protect against in order to secure your sessions from hijack, in addition to XSS. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Comment: I'm specifically worried about sniffing in a compromised android browser.

Comment: If you're worrying about sniffing, then 2 of the most important things to do are to run your service over HTTPS (ensure HTTP always redirects to HTTPS *and exits*) and ensure the secure attribute is set on the cookies to restrict them to to HTTPS only (and also defend against XSS of course. Consider CSRF protection too) .  Note that support for HttpOnly does not help with sniffing attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of the HttpOnly flag is to limit damage in case of Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in the web application by disallowing JavaScript to access the session cookie.  If your web application is written properly in the first place, that is, if it is not vulnerable against XSS, you don't strictly need the HttpOnly flag to be secure from (XSS based) session hijacking.  HttpOnly is only a second line of defense.

So effectively, if you cannot use the HttpOnly flag due to client restrictions, you should make sure to escape all dynamic data properly when including it in HTML, JS, CSS, JSON or whatever format(s) you generate, using the appropriate escaping rules depending on context, to prevent XSS.  Or use a framework which does this for you.

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: My concern isn't *my* application.  I'm worried about trying to defend a session hijack attack on an android browser where someone else tries to steal my cookie.  (For the record, I'm not a pentester, I don't even know if this is a *real* threat.)

Comment: Cookie stealing and session hijacking/fixation are most certainly real threats. However, they can only be solved by recoding the web application whose cookies wish to be safe. There's nothing you can do with your browser as a user, except to not use the service, or ensure you only ever use the HTTPS version of the service (but in the latter, you are still left with a cookie-stealage via man-in-the-middle problem, if cookies are not set to HTTPS only)

Comment: If you are just a user, always ensure you manually log out. If logout is implemented correctly in the server-side webapp, this will reduce the time-window within which an attempt at session hijack can be successful.